# ¿Como copiar un Schema Mysql a otro para modificarlo con otro nombre?

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench, mysqldb

Hola a todos tengo un problema con un Modelo Mysql que estoy tratando de reutilizar. Tengo una base de datos en funcionamiento y lo que quiero hacer es utilizar su Modelo en el Workbrench, hacer unas pequeñas modificaciones como crear un par de tablas nuevas y poco más.
EL problema lo tengo que el que tengo en funcionamiento se llama **portal**, lo abro con workbrench hago las modificaciones y lo guardo con otro nombre, por ejemplo **portal2**. Cuando genero el Script Mysql no me cambia ni el nombre del Schema a la hora de crear las tablas ni el nombre en las referencias. Donde dice portal tanto en DROP TABLE IF EXISTS, CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS como REFERENSE quiero que ponga portal2:

```
 DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `portal`.`usuarios_bloqueados_parcial` ;
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `portal`.`usuarios_bloqueados_parcial` (
 `usuario_idUsuario` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 `idUsuarioBloqueado` INT(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`usuario_idUsuario`, `idUsuarioBloqueado`),
 CONSTRAINT `fk_usuarios_bloqueados_parcial_usuario`
 FOREIGN KEY (`usuario_idUsuario`)
 REFERENCES `portal`.`usuario` (`idUsuario`)
 ON DELETE CASCADE
 ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8mb4
COLLATE = utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Entonces lo que yo quiero hacer es aprovechar todo el modelo que tengo en funcionamiento copiándolo modificar lo que quiera guardarlo con otro nombre y usarlo en otra web.
He intentado hacerlo manualmente en el Script generado al hacer un 'Forward Enginner'en el Workbrench son 24 tablas, pero no es solución por que cada vez que modifique el esquema tendré que modificar el Script.sql. ¿Se puede hacer el 'Forward Enginner' al revés del Script al esquema?.

Comment: Simplemente donde quiera que diga `portal` escribe `portal2`  y luego ejecuta el script. No hay mayor misterio. Si quieres cambiar cualquier otra cosa, como nombres o tipos de columna, también lo puedes hacer **editando el texto del script** antes de ejecutarlo. Cuando lo ejecutes tendrás una nueva tabla `portal2` en blanco.

Comment: Esto es mejor hacerlo desde la línea de comandos, por ejemplo: `mysqldump -u tuNombreDeUsuario –p  -d portal > portal2.sql` Tendrás en `portal2` un nuevo esquema de `portal` sin datos, con todos los `CREATE TABLE` necesarios para replicar el esquema.

Comment: Gracias A.Cedano resulto  ¿Sabes de algún programa que convierta el script en diagrama? Por que ahora cada vez que quiera hacer alguna modificación tengo que hacerlo en el script y me gustaría hacerlo gráficamente como en Workbrench.

Comment: ¿Que convierta el script en diagrama? ¿Con qué finalidad? ¿Es un tipo de operación que tienes que hacer con mucha frecuencia? ¿A qué te refieres con *algún tipo de modificación*? Siempre es más seguro revisar el script uno mismo y si hay que cambiar algo cambiarlo uno mismo, no delegando en terceros programas.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano estoy acostumbrado a trabajar en el workbrench con  los diagramas, es por comodidad. No suelo modificar la bbdd una vez creada y probada. Claro cuando ya esta en funcionamiento con datos si quiero añadir alguna tabla o relación si tengo que hacerlo desde la consola. Pero en este caso es para tener el diagrama y poder verlo, ya se que lo puedo crear por que tengo el portal que es la base y solo he añadido tres tablas y un par de relaciones.-

Comment: Una vez la BD está creada, tú puedes ver su diagrama o lo que sea desde Workbench, tal y como hacías con la BD antigua. Y si quieres modificar cosas puedes hacerlo desde Workbench o desde la consola. Lo que no entendí es lo de hacer *algún tipo de modificación*. Con la BD ya funcionando puedes modificar desde donde quieras sin ningún problema.

Comment: Si A.Cedano pues si el día de mañana quiero añadir una tabla o un campo   a eso me refería. Según lo que sea lo hago por la consola o por worbrench y luego lo ejecuto por la consola. Por ejemplo crear una tabla nueva lo hago por workbrench y  luego lo ejecuto por la consola y si es añadir un campo o modificar lo hago directamente por consola con ALTER TABLE ...

Comment: Eso lo puedes hacer desde Workbench o desde consola, apuntando a la BD correcta, tal y como haces con la BD antigua. Es decir, tanto desde Workbench como desde consola, tú puedes trabajar con cualquier BD que tengas creada.

Comment: Hola A.Cedano perdona no te respondiera ayer pero me tenía que marchar. A ver el tema del diagrama es que como explique al principio yo hice una copia de portal a portal2 y en este hice unas modificaciones. Al generar el Script los CREATE TABLE, etc se referían a la diagrama original osea portal. Esta claro que podía modificarlo manualmente. Tú solución me vale, pero solo tengo un Script para poder crear la bbdd. Pero no  tengo el diagrama de portal2 que pueda modificar en el Workbrench lo que sea y crear un Script nuevo, ya que ese Script tendría que modificarlo otra vez los CREATE TABLE etc

Comment: *yo hice una copia de portal a portal2 y en este hice unas modificaciones. Al generar el Script los CREATE TABLE, etc se referían a la diagrama original osea portal* ... Es precisamente lo que te vengo diciendo. Si tú quieres un diagrama de `portal2` puedes generarlo, entrando en `portal2`. Si el diagrama que se generó es de `portal` es porque estabas en `portal` cuando generaste el diagrama. `portal` ... `portal2`  ... `portal9999` no son que bases de datos, y lo que puedes hacer con una, lo puedes hacer con la otra.

Comment: Pues a ver A.Cedano si yo copio portal.mwb y lo renombro portal2.mwb hago las modificaciones o sin hacer nada y genero el Script me sigue los CREATE TABLE  etc apuntando a la bbdd portal. Si creo otra base de datos llamada portal2 tengo que modificar todo el Script que me ha generado la portal2.mwb.

Comment: Volvamos al principio: si he entendido bien, tú quieres generar un esquema o diagrama a partir de tu base de datos `portal2`, la cual ya tienes replicada y modificada o lo que sea. ¿Entendí bien eso?

Comment: Si eso es lo que busco

Comment: Entonces, ese esquema o diagrama, si he entenido bien, ¿lo generas desde Workbench, usando alguna herramienta que tiene Workbench para ello?

Comment: Hola A.Cedano ayer ya no te pude responder. Ya lo he solucionado es rápido y sencillo, a mi me sonaba esta opción de haberla hecho hace mucho tiempo. Es pinchar en el menú de horizontal de arriba en Database, luego en Reberse Engineer luego eliges el Schema y en unos segundos te genera el diagrama. Aparte de para este caso, gracias por decirme como generar la copia del Script, vale para tener actualizado el EER Model y verlo visualmente. Por que si has modificado cualquier tabla con la consola o añadido o eliminado cualquier cosa es mejor tenerlo gráficamente y no en la mente Gracias A.Cedano